# Is there an Activity inside the workflow that will return me its instance id

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I am running SharePoint 2013 Workflow. I have started my workflow using a custom Initiation form.
Question: Is there an activity that will return me its running instance ID? I need this to pass on to my custom httpSend web service.

Answer (score 2):

How to get Workflow Instance Id in SPD:

Select `Workflow Context` data source and then `Instance ID` field

[image]

### Visual Studio

To get Workflow Instance Id in VS:

- select `LookupWorkflowContextProperty` activity located under `SP -
  Current Context` tab
- and select property name `Instance ID`

[image]

Comment: Vadim:
Thanks for responding....I found Activity "lookupWorflowContextProperty" in VS2013 workkflow.  Which also worked!  Thanks alot for your help.